# clang++ cant find file <iterator>

Tags: libc++, clang++

I am trying to compile my c++ project (working with g++ with boost) with clang. I have successfully compile boost-libraries (1.53) with clang tool-chain. I am using CMake to compile my project, compilation is failing with following error.

```
In file included from /home/dilawar/Works/hpc21/bliff/BlifParserAndPartitioner/src/expression_graph.h:21:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'iterator' file not found
#include <iterator>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I am passing `-stdlib=libc++` to compiler. I am not sure which package I should install (ubuntu) to install libc++. I have clang and llvm installed on my machine.

Do I have to download and compile libc++ or it is installed automatically when one install clang?

Comment: can you post the output of compiler when compiling with '-v' flag. e.g. `clang++ -v -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp`. This will show which are the directories clang is searching to find the included files.

Comment: @AdityaKumar No change in the output with -v switch. I am using cmake. It may be filtering some of the output produced by clang++. Thought I have VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON in cmake.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass -stdlib=libc++ the clang driver looks for header files in a different 
directory w.r.t. when you don't pass the flag. You have to install libc++ separately. The libc++ webpage (http://libcxx.llvm.org/) has some details on how to install libc++ using CMake.

This webpage might also be useful:
http://marshall.calepin.co/llvmclang-and-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x.html